# Get ALL worklog from Jira REST API

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

is there a working REST curl to get all worklog of every issue there is,

I ve tried POST /rest/api/2/worklog/list , but I dont have a list of worklog ids !!

and I don't wanna go through issues either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to go through all the issues, you can get the worklog IDs via [Get ids of worklogs modified since](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-worklog-updated-get) REST API. The response body will contain the IDs you can use for /rest/api/2/worklog/list.

Comment: This, however, will work only in a scenario where you have no more than 1000 worklogs. This endpoint will return only 1000 most recent worklogs. If you have more than 1000 and want to fetch them all, you will have to iterate through issues.

Comment: If there are more than 1000 results, and the result is not the lastpage yet, you can use until from the response as your new since and do another call.

Comment: can someone post a full url ? I keep getting 404s whatever I do and no one ever posts their complete URL (with domain name anonymized)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this POST API : `/rest/tempo-timesheets/4/worklogs/search` which required few request body params as : `{"from":"2018-11-01","to":"2018-11-30","epicKey":["epic-key1"],"projectKey":["project-key1"]}`.

Comment: Does the Jira REST Api for v4 exist? Cause for v3 and v2, no such endpoint exists

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go through issues. The fastest way is to [execute a search](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-search-get) with JQL query: ***worklogDate > 0*** that will return all the issues that have any worklogs. Then you will have to ask for [worklogs of each returned issue](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/#api-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-worklog-get).
Both resources, search results and worklogs of issue are paginated resources so you will have to iterate to get all the worklogs of all the issues (unless you have a small instance).

Answer (score 0):

```
IDS=$(echo {1001..2000} | tr ' ' ',') && curl \
 -u username:password \
 -X POST \
 --data '{"ids":['$IDS']}' \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://jira.com/rest/api/2/worklog/list
```